# Adding environment variable under python

Tags: python, shared-libraries, environment-variables, ctypes

I'm trying to include Matlab shared library in python, if first I'm adding the following variables to the environment variable than the python code works fine:

```
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/MATLAB/R2010b/runtime/glnxa64:/usr/local/MATLAB/R2010b/sys/os/glnxa64:/usr/local/MATLAB/R2010b/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/lib/amd64/native_threads:/usr/local/MATLAB/R2010b/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/lib/amd64/server:/usr/local/MATLAB/R2010b/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/lib/amd64

$ python run.py
```

The content of the run.py

```
from ctypes import *

if __name__ == '__main__':    

    dll = CDLL("/home/robu/Documents/tmo_compile/libmatrix/distrib/libmatrix.so")
```

I tried to add this environment variables in pythyon

```
from ctypes import *

import os

LD_LIBRARY_PATH = "/usr/local/MATLAB/R2010b/runtime/glnxa64:/usr/local/MATLAB/R2010b/sys/os/glnxa64:/usr/local/MATLAB/R2010b/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/lib/amd64/native_threads:/usr/local/MATLAB/R2010b/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/lib/amd64/server:/usr/local/MATLAB/R2010b/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/lib/amd64"
XAPPLRESDIR = "/usr/local/MATLAB/R2010b/X11/app-defaults"

if __name__ == '__main__':    
    os.environ['LD_LIBRARY_PATH'] =  LD_LIBRARY_PATH
    os.environ['XAPPLRESDIR'] =  XAPPLRESDIR

    print os.environ['LD_LIBRARY_PATH']

    dll = CDLL("/home/robu/Documents/tmo_compile/libmatrix/distrib/libmatrix.so")
```

But in this case I'm getting and error

```
OSError: libmwmclmcrrt.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

What am I doing wrong in python?

---

**UPDATED**

I have tried the following:

```
 if(not os.environ.has_key('LD_LIBRARY_PATH')):
        os.environ['LD_LIBRARY_PATH'] =  LD_LIBRARY_PATH
        os.environ['XAPPLRESDIR'] =  XAPPLRESDIR

        os.execve('run.py', (), os.environ)
```

but I'm getting a `OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That environment variable is read by the loader when it's first loaded. It's too late to set it in Python, since the loader was loaded when the Python executable started. You'll need to use `os.exec*()` to replace the current process via running a new executable (and hence loading a new loader).

Comment: Can you give me an example please?

Comment: @KicsiMano:

import sys
python_exe_path = sys.executable
args = [python_exe_path, 'run.py', some_args_if_you_have_any]
os.execve(python_exe_path, args, os.environ) 
Please ensure, that you provide the complete path for 'run.py'